# JQuery Ajax success on new action, failed on edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have two `checkbox` on my `Product` **view** which:

```
<%= f.check_box :can_be_sold %>
<%= f.check_box :can_be_purchased %>
```

And I give several ajax ability to those checkbox to `disable`/`read only` some `textfield` / `select field` just like:

**Application.js.erb** (showing just the caller code):

```
$("#product_can_be_sold").ajaxSelect("products/can_be_sold")
$("#product_can_be_purchased").ajaxSelect("products/can_be_purchased")
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "*module/products/product_can_be_sold" => "products#can_be_sold"
get "*module/products/product_can_be_purchased" => "products#can_be_purchased"
```

The thing is, when on my `http://.../products/new` both work perfectly and nice and tells that routes to `http://.../products/products/can_be_sold`, but when on my edit action which `http://.../products/1/edit` it return an error: `No route matches [GET] "/products/1/products/can_be_sold"`

My analysis was probably wrong on my caller method, I tried to switch, change, but it didn't   solve yet, and I have no idea more to solve this issues.

Thanks.

Comment: If you guys need more code, just tell me, on my `controller` just a `def` with `respond_to` no else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved, my mistake was when on my **routes.rb**.

I look on the code carefully and realize that I should put:

```
get "*module/products/can_be_sold" => "products#can_be_sold"
get "*module/products/can_be_purchased" => "products#can_be_purchased"
```

than:

```
get "*module/products/product_can_be_sold" => "products#can_be_sold"
get "*module/products/product_can_be_purchased" => "products#can_be_purchased"
```

What a stupid mistake, haha.

Thanks